# Using scanner input in getters and setters?

Tags: java

I have two java classes, while one contains the getters and setters the other is a driver class. I need the user input from the scanner in the driver class to be in one of the getters in the first class. The user input has to be a double because it will be used as a formula in the getter.

```
//First Class
public class shopping
{
    String orangeSelected;
    public double getOrangeSelected()
    {
        return (user input makes a formula to be returned to the driver class)
    }

    public void setOrangeSelected(String orangeSelected)
    {
        this.orangeSelected = orangeSelected;
    }
}

//Driver Class
import java.util.Scanner
public class shoppingApp
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner inputOrangeSelected = new Scanner(System.in)
        System.out.println("Premium Oranges");
        String orangeSelected = inputOrangeSelected.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you can't just put the getters and setters in class 1 and delete class 2 entirely? I see no reason to have a whole class of only getters and setters for other classes' instance fields.

Comment: @Levi There have to be two classes. One containing the getters and setters, then the second containing the inputOrangeSelected scanner.

Comment: that sounds like a very bad thing though, is this part of a school assignment?

Comment: @Levi You are correct this is part of an assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What would really be best is to put everything in one class, there is no reason to separate 1 class into 2 just to keep getters and setters separate from the rest, it makes *no sense*. I do wonder if you have misunderstood your assignment.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class shoppingApp
{
    //since it's an instance field not local to the class it's declared here instead of main
    static String orangeSelected = "";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //orange  selected is an odd name for a scanner, just use scan or something similar
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //note that you were missing a semicolon
        System.out.println("Premium Oranges\n"); //include a new line or a space before asking for input, for example with \n
        orangeSelected = scan.nextLine();
    }
    //setter
    public static void setOrangeSelected(String str)
    {
        orangeSelected = str;
    }
    //getter
    public static String getOrangeSelected()
    {
        return orangeSelected;
    }

    //Note that all methods and instance fields are static because the main method must be static if you don't understand this yet that's ok.
}
```

Now if for some reason you absolutely *had* to use two classes it would look something like this, although I'd note that just copying and pasting my code without understanding it would be *cheating*.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class shoppingApp
{
    //normally this shouldn't be public
    public static String orangeSelected = "";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Premium Oranges\n");
        orangeSelected = scan.nextLine();
    }
}

 class gettersAndSetters
{
    //setter
    public void setOrangeSelected(String str)
    {
        Main.orangeSelected = str;
    }
    //getter
    public String getOrangeSelected()
    {
        return Main.orangeSelected;
    }
}
```

Comment: I should also note that in this case there is no reason to actually create the getters and setters anyway because since the instance fields are public you can directly use them without getters/setters.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are facing is that you are not storing the String "orangeSelected" into an instance of your shopping object. In order to do that, you would would to create an instance of your shopping object, and then call the "setOrangeSelected" method.

### Example

Here is how it would look in your driver class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    /* I would recommend changing your shopping class name to Shopping
     for correct naming conventions.*/
    Shopping shopping = new Shopping();

    /* Changed the system out to a question. Not a nessicary change.
     All depends on what your program is doing. */
    System.out.println("What type of oranges would you like?");
    String orangeType = input.nextLine();

    // Here you are actually storing the user input into the shopping object.
    shopping.setOrangeSelected(orangeType);
}
```

Once the input is placed in an object, you can take that variable, and call "getOrangeSelected" on it to return the type of orange, like so:

```
    System.out.println(shopping.getOrangeSelected());
```

### Extra Resources

I suggest you look at the [Oracle naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) for the java language. It is helpful to follow them to improve readability of your code.

### Edit

For clarity, I also wanted to add that you have the getter method return the orangeSelected variable, like so:

```
public double getOrangeSelected() {
    return orangeSelected;
}
```